# Read a text file and use data in it as arguments in a command

Tags: macos, terminal

I am writing a script to run in single user mode on a mac. I am having an issue because I am not able to figure out how to read data from a text file that contains this information

`Guest
Shared
user`

as three lines of unformatted text. I need to cd into these three directories which are subdirectories of /Users in order and run commands in each of the directories. The part Im having an issue with is only the reading of the text data line by line into `cd /Users/$IneedToReadDataHer$/`. If anyone knows how to do this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `cat file | while read i; do xxxx; done` would give you a loop with each row of information as `$i` for each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat file | while read line
do
    cd /Users/"$line"/
    # do something else
done
```